# saved movie in matlab cannot be played

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have created a movie in matlab and I want to save it. I wrote below code to do that, it shows the movie when the code is running correctly but the file which have been saved, can not be played. The error is: "could not determine type of stream"

```
clear all
close all
l = 27;
r = 4; noise_t = 0.02; v0 = 0.1; nn = 300;
x = rand(1,nn).*l; y = rand(1,nn).*l; vx = 0.1.*(rand(1,nn)-0.5.*ones(1,nn)); vy = 0.1.*(rand(1,nn)-0.5.*ones(1,nn)); 
figure('Color',[0 0 0])
axis([0 115 0 40])
axis('square')
hold on
vidObj = VideoWriter('che.avi');
open(vidObj);
time = 900;
neigh=[];
eigh=[];
for t = 1:time;
eig=[];
for number = 1:nn;
distance(1:nn) = (ones(1,nn).*x(number)-x).^2 + (ones(1,nn).*y(number)-y).^2;
neighbour_s = distance < r^2;
eig(1,nn) = sum(neighbour_s);
a = dot(double(neighbour_s),vx)/(sum(neighbour_s));
b = dot(double(neighbour_s),vy)/(sum(neighbour_s));
vx1(number) = a/norm([b,a]); vy1(number) = b/norm([b,a]); mvx(number) = vx1(number); mvy(number) = vy1(number);
end
vx_center = noise_t .*(rand(1,nn)-0.5); vy_center = noise_t .*(rand(1,nn)-0.5); 
vx = mvx + vx_center; vy = mvy + vy_center;    
x = x + vx; y = y + vy;
index = (x < 0); x(index) = rem(x(index),l) + l;
index = (y < 0); y(index) = rem(y(index),l) + l;
index = (x > l); x(index) = rem(x(index),l);
index = (y > l); y(index) = rem(y(index),l);
eigh = [eigh;eig]; 
cla
vecc=eigh(:);
vecc= vecc(find(vecc>0));
hist(vecc,80)
drawnow
currFrame = getframe;
writeVideo(vidObj,currFrame);
drawnow
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary for you to explicitly close the `VideoWriter` object using the [`close` method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/videowriter.close.html) when you are done writing new frames to it. This will finalize the video and make it playable.

```
% At the end of your script
close(vidObj)
```